# How to create a dynamic cache system with PHP and Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching

I have a native app store like google play, I need to load app detail very faster and i don't want select and join tables to create app detail information, I need a dynamic cache system where android app call my web service, web service don't select from database instance select from cache, Do you have any ideas? Note: Speed to load app detail is very important, Do you know google use what mechanism to do this work?

How to keep always cache update?

Comment: Why do you think asking exactly the same again will get any different response to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703370/how-to-create-a-dynamic-cache-system)?

Comment: @mark-baker i edit my own question with current what i want.

Comment: Use a "poor mans cache", create a html file containing the formatted data, then include that where needed if it is less than say, 5 minutes old, else do the long select and recreate the cache. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a query that returns the information you are seeking. MySQL will automatically cache queries results that are executed often. If your query is slow then you may need to refactor your database, or rewrite your queries.

If you need anything beyond that, I'd start By installing the [MySQL Query Results Cache Plugin](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-qc.php) to your server.

> [EXCERPT]
>
> There are four ways to trigger caching of a query.
>
> - Use of SQL hints on a per query basis
> - User supplied callbacks to decide on a per query basis, for example, using mysqlnd_qc_is_select()
> - mysqlnd_set_cache_condition() for rule based automatic per query decisions
> - mysqlnd_qc.cache_by_default = 1 to cache all queries blindly
>
> set rules for automatic caching.
>
> A SQL hint is a SQL standards compliant comment. As a SQL comment it is ignored by the database. A statement is considered eligible for caching if it either begins with the SQL hint enabling caching or it is a SELECT statement.
>
> An individual query which shall be cached must begin with the SQL hint /*qc=on*/. It is recommended to use the PHP constant MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH instead of using the string value.
>
> - not eligible for caching and not cached: INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)
> - not eligible for caching and not cached: SHOW ENGINES
> - eligible for caching but uncached: SELECT id FROM test
> - eligible for caching and cached: /*qc=on*/SELECT id FROM test
>
> The examples SELECT statement string is prefixed with the MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH SQL hint to enable caching of the statement. The SQL hint must be given at the very beginning of the statement string to enable caching.

Comment: *"MySQL and PHP will automatically cache queries"* – uhm, well, **only if you install and configure mysqlnd_qc.** By default nothing will be cached.

Comment: MySQL automatically caches SELECT query results for later see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Yes, but the giant section you quote in your answer needs explicit installation and configuration of a plugin…

Comment: Ahh, yes it does. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: FYI The MySQL docs now states: The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.